# Cry on chest / in cuddle

Tags: word-usage

[image]

I want to describe this picture:

The man is crying on the woman's chest.

The man is crying in the woman's cuddle.

Which one is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: The phrase 'in the cuddle' just doesn't work. A cuddle is not something you can be inside. It is something you partake in.

Comment: "In the woman's cuddle" is not idiomatic.  "In the woman's arms" or "in the woman's embrace" would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Crying on the woman's chest" is literally descriptive.  *Cuddle* is normally not used with expressions of grief.  If what you want is a idiomatic use for comfort through physical contact, use "Crying in the woman's arms."